# NHIbernate OneToOne mapping by code. Access to the specific property

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate in the .NET project. The problem is when I do the mapping OneToOne I am no longer getting string as before, but new ***Person*** type, and that new type has the string field that I want to access.

Is there a way when I do the mapping to explicitly say to the NHibernate fetch me Person->Name or do I need to write specific getter? I

Reason for doing this is because if I use new type, I have to modify multiple calls to the my current property.

```
            OneToOne(x => x.Name, mapper =>
        {
            mapper.PropertyReference(typeof(Person).GetProperty("Name"));
            mapper.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the table structure? It's hard for me to understand which table has Name and on which column it should be joined.

Comment: I did a code refactoring to resolve this. I have changed my string type to Person, and I did refactoring to access Person.Name. I have done it that way because it just fell right, instead of accessing only one field in Person class.